# COVID-19 proof team building activity

Tags: covid-19, team-building

My employer organizes a teambuilding activity every year for the development teams in our company.
I am looking for some ideas where we can still do something, taking social distancing into account.

**I don't want to make this a topic about Covid, but I am looking for a way to still do something with the team.**

Basic COVID rules in Belgium (where the company is based)

- At work, we need to distance ourselves from each other at all times, or we need to wear a mask.
- We cannot do something in groups larger than 10.
- We should avoid touching each other, and things which we all touch.

Situation:

- The team consists of 20 people
- Most, but not all are male

Some ideas I had myself

- Karting
- Paintball
- LAN Party

I am looking for ideas where we still really have the "we did this as a team".

If you think this does not belong in The Workplace, please let me know why and where I can post this question.

Any input?

Comment: Zoom pub quiz. Bring Your Own Bottle.

Comment: Is it an option to split the team into two groups of 10 (at random)?

Comment: City ralley? "Fun park" (the one with rollercoasters)?

Comment: Final vote cast as this is a clear polling / list question and those are unsuitable for this site. Speaking personally as someone from the same location: **this is a terrible idea** and the best approach here is to go virtual for this event and transfer the budget and event to next year when things are hopefully more stable. I'd argue this goes for essentially the entire world right now.

Comment: Virtual "escape room". Scavenger hunts (home/yard-based).

Comment: @Lilienthal, I am wondering, is there any other place on stackexchange I could ask these questions? I notice this kind of question is often closed, while I am genuinely interested in knowing opinions on the topic.

Comment: @Houbie no, this type of question isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange. You might have better luck on a discussion site.

Comment: @Houbie Afraid not. As Kat mentions they're not a good fit. You can find more info on that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad). "*What are good X?*" is almost never on-topic here. Keep in mind that with the new restriction in place in Belgium as of Friday you'll also have to go virtual anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will keep it in mind in the future. Also, thanks for not making a big deal out of it, and explaining what I did wrong.

Comment: musical chairs but use your own chairs

Answer (score 5):

"Team building" and "social distancing" are quite antagonistic.

You might want to play together some online game. This is probably the only solution which could work.

---

> We cannot do something in groups larger than 10.

This reminds me of a training a long time ago, at a previous job. After some team building training the conclusion we drew from the training was:

> A team is always better than a group. But there are things which can be done in a group, which cannot be done in a team.

:)

Which leads to another idea. It can even be done online - even though face-to-face is definitely more attractive: tell jokes and share funny experiences. Everybody contributes. Everybody laughs. Fences fall. Relationships build.

Answer (score 2):

Do a "game-jam". Make sure it can be both digital and traditional games, and make sure the topic of the game-jam is not a traditional "male" interest.

Everyone should join a team of 2-5 people of their own choosing, goal is to make a playable game till the end of the day/weekend/week. Topic can be something like "change" or might be something company-related. Make sure all results are properly honored/presented.

Comment: This seems to be assuming it's a software developing team, which the OP does not say.

Comment: @Erik : Actually no: Game-jams work just as well with creating card games, table-top games or even activity-based games.

Comment: It's indeed a software development team, but the activity should not be focussed on computer things alone ;) Thanks for the input!